# Append string to array elements and join them in one expression

Tags: zsh, array

Let's assume I have an array

```
> words=(foo bar baz)
```

Now I can join the elements

```
> echo ${(j., .)words}
foo, bar, baz
```

And I can append a string to the elements:

```
> echo ${^words}yeah
fooyeah baryeah bazyeah
```

With the following, I can append and join the elements:

```
> wordsyeah=(${^words}yeah)
> echo ${(j., .)wordsyeah}
fooyeah, baryeah, bazyeah
```

Is it possible to do print "fooyeah, baryeah, bazyeah" in a single expression, i.e. without using additional variables?

Bonus: Can I print that without using any variables at all?

As far as I can tell, this boils down to running parameter expansion on strings, but I wasn't able to find out how (or if) that is possible.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37510168/2992551). As per my answer there you could achive this with `echo ${(j:, :):-${^${=:-foo bar baz}}yeah}`, which is actually harder to type and 12 characters longer than `echo fooyeah, baryeah, bazyeah`. So it mainly makes sense if variables are involved, for example `echo ${(j:, :):-${^${words}}yeah} ` (with `words` being an array).

Comment: Wow, you're totally right. I couldn't find that question. Now I'm wondering why I posted this here, too. And I was writing the answer just as you commented. I'll let the mods decide what to do with this question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

```
> print ${(j., .)${:-${^words}yeah}}
fooyeah, baryeah, bazyeah
```

or

```
> print ${(j., .)${:-{foo,bar,baz}yeah}}
fooyeah, baryeah, bazyeah
```

without using variables at all

The critical part is `${name:-word}`. It is explained in [the manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion).

> ```
> ${name-word}
> ${name:-word}
> ```
>
> If name is set, or in the second form is non-null, then substitute its value; otherwise substitute word. **In the second form name may be omitted, in which case word is always substituted.**

Thanks to phy1729 from #zsh for pointing this out to me :)

Comment: Can you please accept your own answer, so this question doesn't stay marked as "unanswered"? Thanks!